# Como anunciar IP de servidor na rede?

Tags: node.js, conexão, redes

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação composta por um servidor feito em `NodeJS` que deve fornecer dados em `JSON` para os clientes, no caso um aplicativo para `Android`, tudo funcionando em rede interna.

Já consegui fazer todo o processo de comunicação e tudo funciona da forma esperada, porém estou definindo o IP e porta do servidor de forma fixa tanto no servidor quanto no cliente (por exemplo 192.168.1.15:3300).

Gostaria de saber se existe uma forma de anunciar o IP do servidor na rede já que este pode mudar em algum momento, como por exemplo nos jogos online, onde é mostrado uma lista com servidores ligados.

Já pensei em fazer um escaneamento da porta do meu servidor em toda a rede, porém este processo pode se tornar lento, ainda mais que o cliente pode não ter muito poder de processamento.

**Existe alguma forma mais rápida ou melhor para "anunciar"o IP do servidor na rede para que os clientes possam se conectar?**

Comment: Olha se entendi o que você quer é que os clientes saibam qual o IP está distribuindo o JSON, não seria melhor fixa-lo? Eu não sei se entendi o que você necessita

Comment: No exemplo atual está fixo como comentado, porém pode ocorrer do servidor alterar o IP por algum motivo e não conseguir mais o IP fixado nos clientes. Preciso que o servidor de alguma forma conte em que IP está executando. Mas Obrigado pelo comentário de qualquer forma.

Comment: Entendi, se o IP é somente local acredito o rastreamento não seja lento, se você utilizar algo como `try { Socket socket = new Socket(); socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ip, 3300), timeout); socket.close(); return true; } catch (Exception ex) { return false;  }` e um loop

Comment: Não dá pra usar DNS? Simplificaria.

Comment: Não é possível fazer um loop sobre os IP's, imagina algo como 200 clientes conectados, agora imagina fazer um loop sobre os 200 IP's (se o servidor for o último é claro) feito por um Smartphone e isso sem considerar o Timeout. Fiz uns teste com 30 IPs e já levou mais de 1 minuto para descobrir o servidor. Talvez exista algum algorítimo melhor. Posso ter feito algo errado.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pedro, de fato vasculhar a rede procurando pelo serviço/dispositivo é inviável, principalmente se você não pode usar algo como [nmap](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nmap) (com [algum binding para o nodejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-libnmap)) no dispositivo cliente.

A minha sugestão é que você não implemente nada na mão e utilize protocolos já conhecidos para esta finalidade, por exemplo o [SSDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Service_Discovery_Protocol).

> O **protocolo simples de descoberta de serviços** (SSDP) é um protocolo de rede do conjunto de protocolos da internet, para divulgação e descoberta de serviços de rede e presença de informação. **Ele cumpre este objetivo sem assistência de mecanismos de configuração baseados em servidor, como o [DHCP](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol) ou o [DNS](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System), e sem configurações estáticas**. O SSDP é a base do protocolo de descoberta do [Universal Plug and Play (UPnP)](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play).

O SSDP é um protocolo baseado em [HTTPU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPU) que é uma extensão do HTTP 1.1 utilizando o UDP como camada de transporte.

O servidor anuncia o serviço disponível fazendo multicast IP para a porta **1900**. O range de endereço multicast é [239.0.0.0 - 239.255.255.255](http://www.iana.org/assignments/multicast-addresses/multicast-addresses.xhtml#multicast-addresses-12). É utilizado o verbo HTTP `NOTIFY` para anunciar ou notificar a desativação de um serviço.

Para um cliente descobrir serviços disponíveis em uma rede é utilizado o verbo `M-SEARCH` e respostas para estes requests são devolvidos em [*unicast* (comunicação um-a-um)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicast) para o mesmo endereço e porta que o originou.

#### Esclarecendo

Na arquitetura da sua aplicação ambos os clientes (smartphones) e o servidor vão escutar e emitir mensagens. Inicialmente, quando ninguém conhece ninguem pode haver duas situações:

1- O servidor acabou de entrar na rede, suponha que o seu servidor acabou de voltar de um reboot - ele então faz multicast para todos na rede, na porta 1900 com UDP, enviando um verbo `NOTIFY`, com todas as informações necessárias da sua localização na rede (ip e porta). Os clientes (smartphones) que já estão escutando na porta 1900 recebem o request e a partir daí usam esta informação como bem entenderem.

2- Um novo cliente acabou de entrar na rede e quer descobrir o servidor. Ele então envia um multicast para a porta 1900, com o verbo `M-SEARCH`. O servidor recebe esta requisição e retorna a requisição para o mesmo endereço e porta originários, o cliente recebe o retorno e faz o que bem entender com a informação.

#### Porque usar tudo isso?

Para você não ter a necessidade de criar o seu próprio protocolo de descoberta de serviços e não perder tempo desenvolvendo bibliotecas que já lidam com isso. O node já tem módulos que abstraem esse tipo de problema e aposto que existem bibliotecas para os smartphones que também já o fazem.

#### Como implementar tudo isso?

1- Você implementa tudo na mão, ou
2- Você pode usar o módulo [super-ssdp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/super-ssdp) que é super simples e tem uma API minúscula:

```
var ssdp = require('super-ssdp'),
    ip = require('ip'),
    porta = (Math.random() * 10000).toFixed(0), // Porta fake. Coloque aqui a porta do seu serviço principal
    peer = ssdp.createPeer({
        name: 'suaAplicação',
        url: 'http://' + ip.address() + ':' + porta
    });

peer.start();

peer.on('found', function(endereco) {
    console.log('Serviço encontrado!', endereco);
});
```

Para testar o código acima você precisa fazer o seguinte; `npm install super-ssdp ip` e então `node app.js` (ou o nome do arquivo que você preferir). Agora abra outro terminal (para simular um outro dispositivo) e rode o último comando novamente. Preferencialmente teste em outro computador conectado a rede.

#### Mais Testes

Vamos testar que qualquer cliente, smartphone no seu caso, é capaz de encontrar o servidor.

Em uma aba de terminal rode o código acima, em outra rode este

```
var dgram = require('dgram'),
    ip = require('ip');

//0- Este é o nosso request HTTPU
var msearch = new Buffer(
    'M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
    'HOST:239.255.255.250:1900\r\n' +
    'MAN:\"ssdp:discover\"\r\n' +
    'ST:ssdp:all\r\n' +
    'MX:3\r\n' +
    '\r\n'
);

//1- Criamos um socket para enviar o M-SEARCH e escutar a resposta
var client = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

//2- Este socket escuta numa porta que o proprio SO vai designar,
//   e em todos os endereços, não apenas localhost
client.bind(function() {
    client.on('message', function(msg, rinfo) {
        //3- Aqui trataremos a reposta
        if(rinfo.address !== ip.address()) {
            //4- Só estamos interessados em mensagens vindas do localhost.
            //   Se você não colocar este `if` você vai receber varias mensagens
            //   do seu roteador, por exemplo!
            return;
        }

        //5- Imprimimos a resposta que contem o IP e porta do servidor.
        //   O ideal aqui seria fazer um parse da resposta.
        console.log(msg.toString());
    });

    //6- Enviamos o M-SEARCH para todo mundo, repare a porta e o endereço multicast
    client.send(msearch, 0, msearch.length, 1900, '239.255.255.250', function() {
        console.log('M-SEARCH enviado...');
    });
});
```

No código acima implementamos na mão o código de um cliente SSDP, que é justamente o que a biblioteca para Android ou iOS deve fazer para você.

Nós até poderíamos implementar outro teste em que o o servidor 2 envia um `NOTIFY` para o servidor1 mas [a biblioteca `super-ssdp` não implementou o handler para `NOTIFY`](https://github.com/guerrerocarlos/super-ssdp/blob/master/index.js#L29-L30) então não tem como testar. Na verdade essa biblioteca não é consolidada, [o único like que ela tem no GitHub é o meu kkk](https://github.com/guerrerocarlos/super-ssdp/stargazers) - você provavelmente vai querer encontrar algo mais testado e consolidado, as vezes algo até fora do node mesmo e aí você só cria os bindings.

[O seu problema](https://www.google.com/search?q=ssdp+client+for+android&oq=ssdp+client+for+android&aqs=chrome..69i57.2631j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8) ([ou não](https://www.google.com/search?q=ssdp+ios&oq=ssdp+ios&aqs=chrome..69i57.4453j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8)) será encontrar uma biblioteca que implemente o SSDP na linguagem/plataforma dos smartphones.

Answer (score 5):

Como é rede interna acho que o mais simples seria o servidor soltar um pacote UDP broadcast (ou multicast) a intervalos regulares "anunciando" sua existência.

Talvez esses links ajudem:

- http://nodejs.org/api/dgram.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14130560/nodejs-udp-multicast-how-to
- https://gist.github.com/ciaranj/9056285

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada, de cara posso falar que talvez Broadcast cause problemas. Vou fazer um protótipo com MultiCast e ver se apresenta um resultado bom.

Comment: Uma alternativa para diminuir o tráfego, apesar de UDP ser compacto por natureza, seria o cliente mandar um broadcast ao conectar e o servidor responder só quando solicitado, se a quantidade de clientes não for gigantesca.